Email Signature HTMLbody not displaying image
I've got the following code, the issue is that in the signature there is an image that won't display at the end of the codethe error in the signature
I am looking for a solution so the image also displays. Note that when i first display the mail, the signature is complete with image.
The code is as follows:
Sub Email()
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Status" Then
    MsgBox "This macro can only be executed from the Status sheet!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim Signature As Variant
Dim Overview As Variant
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Mypath As String
Dim maillist As String

Dim rng As Range
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set sh = Sheets("Status")
Set rng = sh.Range("B2:W61")
       rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = OutMail.getinspector.WordEditor
    LastMember = Worksheets("Info").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
    
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("M2:M" & LastMember).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If cell.Value Like "*" Then
            maillist = maillist & ";" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next
    
    Mypath = """" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & """"
    strbody = "<p>Dear all,</p>" & "Please find below basware overview of today" & "<br/>" & "<A href=" & Mypath & ">Click here to open the file</A>"
    
On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .display
        .To = maillist
        .CC = "EMAILADDRESS@EMAIL.COM"
        .Subject = "AP - Basware Overview - " & Date
        Signature = .htmlBody
        wdDoc.Range.pasteandformat Type:=wdChartPicture
        With wdDoc
        .inlineShapes(1).Height = 800
        End With
        Overview = .htmlBody
        .htmlBody = strbody & Overview & Signature

    End With
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```


a) href needs to be enclosed in brackets and b) you cannot construct valid HTML like this strbody & Overview & Signature. Maybe start here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/

FYI. Delete On Error Resume Next in any code where it appears immediately before With OutMail. If an error occurs fix it.
